# Display WYSIWYG editor group names to endusers modifying content

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

When one is editing the Toolbar Configuration in a Text Format in Drupal 8, group names can be added to the editor as part of grouping the buttons in the toolbar.

Is it possible to expose those group names to endusers who use the editor to edit content? If so, how?

Comment: CKEditor doesn't seem to have an option for that (https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html), but the name is actually there, just hidden. If you add this CSS rule to the page it will display: `.cke_toolbar .cke_voice_label { display: block; }`